# how to avoid garbage values in GPA Calculator?

Tags: java, combobox, project

I'm new to programming. I'm learning java and working on a mini project which include calculating student GPA.

There is a logical error in my results. The result is correct the first time the user enters the grades. Then they will be all garbage. I tried to clear my variables after the first time but still there is the problem when the user enters the grade wrong and decides to change it. This results in garbage results, too.

```
Course1 = new JTextField();
    Course1.setText("Course 1");
    Course1.setBounds(20, 237, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(Course1);
    Course1.setColumns(10);
Hours1 = new JComboBox();
    Hours1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
{

            if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {

                String h =(String) Hours1.getSelectedItem();
                currentHour=Integer.parseInt(h);
                totalHours+=currentHour;
            }
        }
    });
    Hours1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {" ","2", "3", "4",              
            "5"}));
    Hours1.setBounds(135, 237, 39, 20);
    contentPane.add(Hours1);
Grade1 = new JComboBox();
    Grade1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                String grade=(String)Grade1.getSelectedItem();
                switch(grade)
                {
                    case "A+": 
                        currentPoint=5*currentHour;

                        break;
                    case "A": 
                        currentPoint= 4.75 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "B+": 
                        currentPoint= 4.5 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "B": 
                        currentPoint= 4 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "C+": 
                        currentPoint= 3.5 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "C": 
                        currentPoint= 3 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "D+": 
                        currentPoint= 2.5 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "D": 
                        currentPoint= 2 * currentHour;
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        currentPoint= 1 * currentHour;
                        break;
                }
                myPoints=myPoints+currentPoint;
            }
        }
    });
    Grade1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {" ","A+", "A", "B+",  
            "B", "C+", "C", "D+", "D", "F"}));
    Grade1.setBounds(204, 237, 47, 20);
    contentPane.add(Grade1);
```

I wrote the same code for every course which also bothers me, because I want more efficient program.

Comment: what is Grade1 ? and currentHour? and myPoints ? what have you initialized them to ?

Comment: Grade1 is the first combobox in my list , currentHour is a temp variable to store the credit hours of a course. I declared it as instance variable so that the other comboboxes will use it. there is also a variable called totalHours to store the total number of hours the user entered, I add the value of currentHour to totalHours everytime. myPoints is a variable to store the total number of earned points, It will be divided by the maximum possible points and then will be multiplied by 5 to get the GPA out of 5.

Comment: I suggest you to add the rest of the code as well, because it is important to know the flow of the code. what have you set myPoint equal to at declaration ?

Comment: nothing. I thought instance variables are initialized to 0 by default then we manipulate them inside methods.

Comment: try reinitializing the variable to 0 at the point where you begin your calculation again.

Comment: You want the whole program ? because the other parts are similar to what I have just added

Comment: But what if the user changed the grade at some point other than the first grade, then it will initialize the variables to 0 , destroy the previous values and the result will be garbage

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand your questions 100%.  But here's my thought.  You might need a "default" in the "switch case" structure for when the users has typed something other than their grades.

BTW, you have two extra curly braces at the end of the code you have pasted.  I assumed you have just pasted it wrong.

Comment: sorry , there are missing information because I couldn't upload the image.  Actually, the credit hours and grades are comboboxes, the user will only choose. The 2 additional braces are pasted by mistake. They enclose the itemStateChanged method and the anonymous class (listener).

Comment: default has nothing to do with garbage values